# Ignoring symlinks in git

Tags: windows, linux, git, symlink, shortcut

Is there a way to make git completely ignore symlinks (leave them in the tree, but not create them on checkout)?  Alternatively, is there a way to make git convert between symlinks on linux and shortcuts on windows?

Context: I'm using git with some LaTeX files on both windows and linux.  On linux, I have a large number of style files stored outside the repo, and symlinked to from a bunch of places.  It'll work fine if git turns them into shortcuts on windows (I have the same surrounding directory/file structure), or if git ignores them completely, and doesn't check them out (I have the style files in my LaTeX distribution on windows).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore symbolic links in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511312/ignore-symbolic-links-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 6):

On the "ignoring symlink" side, you could set the [config **`core.symlinks`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) configuration variable to **`false`** (as a local config within the Windows Git repo):

Symlinks would be checked out as small plain text files that contain the path of the file system object that it links to, but without creating said target object.

Comment: If I'm ignoring symlinks, then I want the files by that name to not appear.  Having small text files by the name of the symlink breaks LaTeXing.

Comment: @Jason: then I can only see a post-checkout hook moving all those files out of the way, plusupdating the index to "assume-ignore" them (in order to not detect the fact they are missing): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633681/git-ignoring-version-controlled-files

Comment: Do post-checkout hooks get called on, e.g., `git reset --hard`?

Comment: @Jason: don't sure, but I don't think so (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639342/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-and-git-checkout)

Comment: Even worse, I have a similar problem, but I might have symlinks with the same name in repos on two different computers, but pointing to different places. A post-checkout hook won't work with that setup, will it?

Comment: @naught101 it could help if the goal of that post-checkout hook is just to get rid of those symlink files.