# git: how to ignore symlinks?

Tags: git, symlink, git-config

I have a local git repo in a directory that contains soft links (Linux), and I'd like to ignore those links so that `git status` etc. won't bother about these links. I am using git v2.34.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190626/1556746) proposes to set `core.symlinks` to `false`, which I did in the local `.git/config` and cross-checked by means of

```
$ git config --get core.symlinks
false
```

Despite of that setting, git is still showing the links with `git status`.  I know I can add all them symlinks to `.gitignore` by hand (or by means of a script for that matter).

So what part am I missing?

The [documentation of `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore/2.32.0) has only two mentions of *"symbolic link"* which don't answer my question, so presumably it's not a feature of git as of v2.32 ?

Comment: What you're missing is that you did not read what https://stackoverflow.com/a/5190626/341994 actually says.

Comment: The linked question is about checking-out already-tracked symbolic links. If you want to ignore untracked files, you'll need to use a gitignore file or `core.excludesFile`.

Comment: @Brian61354270: So what is the magic command to ignore simlinks in `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't have a built-in feature to ignore symlinks.  If there are paths that you don't want to include in your repository, whether those are symlinks or not, then you can specify them in `.gitignore`, and Git will ignore them if they are untracked.  You will have to list them explicitly by filename, since the `.gitignore` file doesn't provide a way to select different file types.  You can, however, ignore a directory with a trailing slash (e.g., `foo/`) to ignore the directory and its entire contents.

If they are already tracked, then you'll want to use `git rm --cached` to remove them from the index so that they are untracked, and then ignoring them will be effective.  Git [doesn't offer a way to ignore tracked files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).

In general, you want to avoid modifying `core.symlinks`.  That value is an internal value determined by Git to remind itself whether the OS and file system in question support symlinks (since, on Windows, symlinks may require elevated permission you may not have).  It isn't designed to be modified by the user, and it won't result in the behaviour you want anyway.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way (current) git can do it. Thanks.

Comment: Adding the folder to `.gitignore` does not work: Adding `../folder/` has not the desired effect, nor has `../folder/*` or `../folder/*.*` etc. What also doesn't work is adding `../` or `../*` or `*/folder/`.

Comment: You can't use `..`.  If your folder is `foo/bar`, relative to the root of the repository, put the `.gitignore` in the root of the repository, and use `/foo/bar/`.

Comment: The `.gitignore` *is* at the root of the repo, i.e. in the same folder where `.git` resides. It's the symbolic links that are of the form `../folder/file.xyz`.

Comment: You're not specifying the destination of the symbolic link, but it's name.  If the symbolic link's name is `foo/bar/baz`, then you can ignore `/foo/bar/` or `/foo/bar/baz`, but the destination is irrelevant and not considered.