# Same file in different locations in GIT

Tags: git, git-add

How to add a same file in different locations in GIT on same branch
If i update in one place it should reflect in other place also

Here is the flow

file a.txt under directory "DIR 1" 
and i need same file under directory "DIR 2 "

If I commit /update anything on a.txt it should reflect two places.

I used symbolic links no use is there any way to get it down ?

Comment: What's the problem with symlinks? They should work fine. Can you paste the problem you're facing?

Comment: it is not reflecting the latest version..

Answer (score 2):

[Symbolic links](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) are one correct way, but on Windows, you need to be careful as how you register them in your Git repo:

See "[Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754068/6309)", for the right post-checkout script in order to correctly update/restore the content referenced by those symlinks.

Comment: register them?  how do you register them?

Comment: @blamb with a git add. They are now supported with Windows 10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49913019/6309