# Can I test my app in a EGit repository with Xampp locally?

Tags: eclipse, git, testing, xampp, egit

I am having trouble setting up the testing mentioned in the title because of the folder structures for Xampp and Git/EGit respectively. Can anyone recommend a guide or tutorial on how to do this?

Given Xampp is looking for the .htdocs/appname/ folder for testing the app but folder structure can be something like .htdocs/repositoryname/appfoldername, they are hard to match. Has anyone solved this?

Or should I be testing with some other software which is suitable for testing PHP projects in Git repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a symbolic link ([even on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754068/6309)) in order for `.httdocs/appname` to refer to `.htdocs/repository/appfoldername` (with option `Options FollowSymLinks` set in the `<Directory>` section of your Xampp `httd.conf` file)

---

The [OP alieninlondon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469742/alieninlondon) reports:

> I found another very easy way.
>   Simply by putting the repository directory in the `.htdocs` folder and then accessing the app through `localhost/repositoryfolder/appfolder` in my webbrowser worked perfectly for me.

Comment: thanks for that! also, I found another very easy way. simply by putting the repository directory in the .htdocs folder and then accessing the app through http://localhost/repositoryfolder/appfolder/ in my webbrowser worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @alieninlondon Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.