# Git hooks for symlink convertion on Windows

Tags: windows, git, hook, symlink

I tried make git hooks on Windows to do automatically convert unix symlinks located in repository to hardlinks+junctions windows on local machine. How I may do this? We use a mix of Windows and Unix based OS's.

I extended Git's command list like this [Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows/16754068#16754068)

I read about hooks and created post-checkout hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec git rm-symlinks
```

It works, when I execute git checkout #branch_with_symlink, but when I do next checkout, git wrote:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
#path_to_symlink
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
```

git status:

```
# On branch #branch_with_symlink
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

git haven't pre-checkout hook, and I don't understand, how i make this convertion

Comment: I have the same problem (same error that doesn't let me switch branch even if there are no changes). The difference with you is that I created the Junction points manually (in Windows 8). It seems there is a problem with git. If you find a solution please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a hook, you could try using a smudge filter.  They're more designed to change the content of text files than of symlinks, but I think you could get them to work.

Some documentation here: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#__code_filter_code