# Using symlinks between two projects on git

Tags: linux, windows, git, symlink

There is server running under `CentOS` with `php-fpm` and `nginx` on aboard. Two projects are hosted, one of them is primary, the second contains half of the primary project as symlinks and part corresponding to itself. Both projects are in git repos. The primary project works correct under Linux and Windows machines after cloning the repo. But the second project contains symlinks and it doesn't work properly.

I don't know what to do. It's important to save the symlinks, but how should we work with the second project on Windows? Some hooks with git (replace symlinks with files before pull)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` converts symlinks to text files on Windows, since symlinks are available only on `*nix` environments, and `msysgit` doesn't take care of them by default.

You can create a `post-commit` hook to workaround them.

Check answers on [git symlinks in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows), specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754068/1860929) where a user has given steps to handle the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for git submodules: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: It's not for this case, it's not a cure for symlinks