# Git Symlinks - Windows Workstation - Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows, git, netbeans, symlink

I do PHP development on a Windows 7 workstation using Netbeans. Netbeans sychronizes files with a remote Linux server that is where the code is executed. If I change branches, and there's a new symlink, Netbeans will upload the text file to my remote server, which breaks the symlink. Is there a way to have git ignore symbolic links altogether? Perhaps a different solution altogether?

Comment: you should be able to pick and choose which files you commit.. simply don't commit those symlinked directories.

Comment: It looks like this guy has had some luck with a custom solution. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows)

Comment: Thanks @AlanAsher, but neither of those really address the question that I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a **real** filesystem that supports symlinks, windows isn't well known for mounting other file systems I'm afraid.

Maybe you could run a virtualbox VM and use the Shared File-system option. Otherwise Netbeans surely also includes the ability to mount a remote unix filesytem..

In fact WinSCP can do that for you I believe but it seems like such a pain.

Of course you could just run Netbeans on linux or OSX. I highly recommend mint cinnamon to all my developers and only one of 9 (and counting) has reverted to win7.  They love their sshfs connections direct to the dev servers  ;-)

Comment: OK, I found it: http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/ - Why would you use that over Ubuntu?