# How can I make `javaSource` directory different from `sourceDirectory` / main / java?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have old and big Java project in which I want to start using Scala. All Java sources are stored in `/src`. Unfortunately I cannot move them to standard `/src/main/java` directory because there are tons of old Ant scripts and etc.

So my goal is to have new Scala source **and resources** in `/srcnew` and keep Java stuff in `/src`. So I wrote following in `build.scala`

```
sourceDirectory := baseDirectory.value / "srcnew",
javaSource := baseDirectory.value / "src",
```

And it doesn't work :) SBT doesn't see source in `javaSource` at all.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Maybe just symlink it?

Comment: Have you seen ["Customizing paths"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html) in the SBT docs?

Comment: @ChrisMartin Actually not bad idea :) I'll talk to guys tomorrow. But I suspect it might be hard to do because it will require manual action on multiple build servers and on every developer's machine.

Comment: Why, what kind of version control are you using? You can check symlinks into a git repo.

Comment: @ChrisMartin We're using GitHub but according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows making git symlinks in Windows is phenomenal pain.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about Windows ;)

Comment: @ChrisMartin It's offtopic but while we're on the subject could you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/28016458/226895 ?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `javaSource` with `javaSource in Compile` like in the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the examples from  ["Customizing paths"](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html) in the SBT docs:

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"

scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-src"

javaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"

javaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-src"
```

So in your case it would be

```
sourceDirectory in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "srcnew"

javaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
```