# Setting `unmanagedResourceDirectories` breaks deployment of resources from `resourceDirectory`

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a little bit odd setup. My Java sources are located at
`/src`

There are `.properties` files next to some Java classes. I want them to be packaged to final jar.

Scala sources and resources follow SBT convention and are located at
`/srcnew/main/[scala|resources]`

Here is how my `build.scala` looks like

```
sourceDirectory := baseDirectory.value / "srcnew",
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "src"),
includeFilter in unmanagedResources := "*.properties",
javaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src",
```

Even though `resourceDirectory` still points to `/srcnew/main/resources` resources don't make it to final jar (built with sbt-assembly).

I also tried

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories  := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "src", baseDirectory.value / "srcnew/main/resources"),
```

and surprisingly it doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that problem was in line

```
includeFilter in unmanagedResources := "*.properties"
```

instead it should be

```
includeFilter in unmanagedResources := ((includeFilter in unmanagedResources).value || "*.properties") -- "*.java",
```

the only thing I don't understand is why filter on `unmanagedResources` affects `resourceDirectory`. Does anyone know ?