# Adding a custom resource directory to SBT's default unmanagedResourceDirectories

Tags: scala, sbt

I have two SBT projects as outlined below.

```
├── Project 1
│    │
│    └── src
│         └── main
│               ├── scala
│               │     └── com
│               │           └── xyz
│               │                 └── <*.scala>
│               └── resources
│                      └── <Typesafe & Log4J config files> 
│   
│   
└── Project 2
     │
     ├── src
     │    └── main
     │          ├── scala
     │          │     └── com
     │          │           └── xyz
     │          │                 └── <*.scala>
     │          └── resources
     │                 └── <Typesafe & Log4J config files> 
     │
     ├── resources 
     │     └── <JS, HTML, Image files etc.> 
     ├── other-dir-1 
     │
     ├── other-dir-2 
     │
     └── other-dir-3
```

Compiling Project 1 (actually running SBT `exportedProducts` task) produces the following directory structure. `unmanagedResourceDirectories` points to `Project1/src/main/resources`. I believe this is the default `resourceDirectory` (as mentioned in [Customizing Paths](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html)). In other words, files in default resource directory are automatically added by `exportedProducts`

```
├── Project 1
     └── target
           └── scala-2.10
                 └── classes
                       ├── com
                       │    └── xyz
                       │         └── <*.class>
                       └── <Typesafe & Log4J config files>
```

For Project 2, I want the following directory structure to be produced by `exportedProducts`.

```
├── Project 2
     └── target
           └── scala-2.10
                 └── classes
                       ├── com
                       │    └── xyz
                       │         └── <*.class>
                       ├── <Typesafe & Log4J config files>
                       │
                       └── resources 
                             └── <JS, HTML, Image files etc.>
```

To do this I added the following to SBT build file in the appropriate project definition.

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value
excludeFilter in unmanagedResources := HiddenFileFilter || "other-dir-*" 
includeFilter in unmanagedResources :=
    new SimpleFileFilter(_.getCanonicalPath.startsWith((baseDirectory.value / "resources").getCanonicalPath))
```

This correctly includes `resources` directory but doesn't include the files from `Project2\src\main\resources`. The `target` directory looks like the

```
├── Project 2
     └── target
           └── scala-2.10
                 └── classes
                       ├── com
                       │    └── xyz
                       │         └── <*.class>
                       └── resources 
                             └── <JS, HTML, Image files etc.>
```

Adding a custom resource directory in some way masks the content of the default resource directory. I tried something along the lines of what was mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016458/setting-unmanagedresourcedirectories-breaks-deployment-of-resources-from-reso) but wasn't successful.

The other thing that I tried was to set `unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile += baseDirectory.value / "resources"` and remove both `includeFilter` and `excludeFilter`. This adds the files from `Project2\src\main\resources` correctly but adds the files & directories from `Project2\resources` directly to `Project2\target\scala-2.10\classes`. The `target` directory looks like the following

```
├── Project 2
     └── target
           └── scala-2.10
                 └── classes
                       ├── com
                       │    └── xyz
                       │         └── <*.class>
                       ├── <Typesafe & Log4J config files>
                       │
                       └── <JS, HTML, Image files etc.>
```

Comment: Why not just move the js/html/image stuff into Project2/src/main/resources/resources?