# How can I make the Openshift "Ruby on Rails 4" "instant app" work on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, openshift

When I create the app using Openshift and then clone the repository to Windows and try to run it locally using "rails server" it fails because the repository includes Linux symlink files:

```
    lib/openshift_secret_generator.rb -> .openshift/lib/openshift_secret_generator.rb
    config/initializers/secret_token.rb -> .openshift/config/secret_token.rb
    config/initializers/session_store.rb -> .openshift/config/session_store.rb
```

If I replace the link files with the files they are pointing to that solves the problem on Windows, but when I push the changes the app will no longer run on Openshift:

```
remote: cannot load such file -- /var/lib/openshift/5511d2834382ec31640000c4/app-root/runtime/repo/lib/openshift_secret_generator.rb
remote: /var/lib/openshift/5511d2834382ec31640000c4/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote: /var/lib/openshift/5511d2834382ec31640000c4/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
remote: /var/lib/openshift/5511d2834382ec31640000c4/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
remote: /var/lib/openshift/5511d2834382ec31640000c4/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
remote: /var/lib/openshift/5511d2834382ec31640000c4/app-root/runtime/repo/config/initializers/secret_token.rb:2:in `'
...
```

How do I get the app to run on Windows and Openshift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git Symlinks in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows)