# How to add symlink file to a gitlab repo

Tags: git, gitlab, symlink, gitlab-ci

How can I add symlink to file to gitlab repository?

Every time I run a pipeline from gitlab, the local symlink gets destroyed.

Any suggestions on how to create a symlink for a folder which resides inside of gitlab repo would be great.

Answer (score 3):

You can store in  a Git repo a [symlink (special entry 12000)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791647/6309), but, as seen in [this test](https://gitlab.com/wtsi-hgi/test-gitlab-ci-symlink/commit/469d23da8ce4d6d358cb7a40f43ac653df7ef267), that would make the [GitLab pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) fail.
See [gitlab-ce issue 27542](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/27542) (though it is for the particular case of  `.gitlab-ci.yml` being a symlink).

It is best if the pipeline first recreate the symlink, then process in its subsequent steps, with the normal build: regenerating it seems better than storing it.

Comment: is there any solution to this problem? Its almost 2years.