# How to add symlinks to git repository on Windows?

Tags: git, symlink, git-add

I compile binaries for OS X using GitHub' s electron environment and want to add the output to a git repository.

I tried

```
git add .
error: readlink("sulu.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file sulu.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
fatal: adding files failed
```

Any idea to work around this?

Comment: I'm not confident enough or motivated enough to submit a patch for git, but if anyone is interested most Windows these days support something equivalent to a symlink. Look into `mklink /J symlink/path target/path`. Notice that /J doesn't need admin permissions. I know it doesn't help you but hopefully someone will submit a patch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5917249/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows command

```
mklink /H "Link_File_Path" "Target_File_Path"
```

Use above command to create a hard link for all your output files. That will work. I did similar stuff for git hooks.

Refer this link for more info about `mklink` http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html