# Vagrant - paver devstack error: "[Errno 20] Not a directory"

Tags: git, vagrant, devstack, edx, openedx

I am attempting to get edx Devstack installed with Vagrant, and I'm on a Windows machine.  I'm getting errors that appear to result from symlinks that aren't supported by Windows.

According to the edx troubleshooting guide under [Dealing with line endings and symlinks under Windows](https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/Vagrant-troubleshooting#dealing-with-line-endings-and-symlinks-under-windows), I should run the following commands in cygwin to deal with symlinks.

```
git rm --cached -r . && git reset --hard

git config --global alias.add-symlink '!__git_add_symlink(){
    dst=$(echo "$2")/../$(echo "$1"); 
    if [ -e "$dst" ]; then 
        hash=$(echo "$1" | git hash-object -w --stdin); 
        git update-index --add --cacheinfo 120000 "$hash" "$2"; 
        git checkout -- "$2"; 
    else 
        echo "ERROR: Target $dst does not exist!"; 
        echo "       Not creating invalid symlink."; 
    fi; 
    }; __git_add_symlink "$1" "$2"'

git config --global alias.rm-symlink '!__git_rm_symlink(){
    git checkout -- "$1"; link=$(echo "$1"); 
    POS=$'\''/'\''; DOS=$'\''\\\\'\''; 
    doslink=${link//$POS/$DOS}; 
    dest=$(dirname "$link")/$(cat "$link"); 
    dosdest=${dest//$POS/$DOS}; 
    if [ -f "$dest" ]; then 
        rm -f "$link"; 
        cmd //C mklink //H "$doslink" "$dosdest"; 
    elif [ -d "$dest" ]; then 
        rm -f "$link"; 
        cmd //C mklink //J "$doslink" "$dosdest"; 
    else 
        echo "ERROR: Something went wrong when processing $1 . . ."; 
        echo "       $dest may not actually exist as a valid target."; 
    fi; 
    }; __git_rm_symlink "$1"'

git config --global alias.rm-symlinks '!__git_rm_symlinks(){
    for symlink in `git ls-files -s | grep -E "^120000" | cut -f2`; 
    do 
        git rm-symlink "$symlink"; 
        git update-index --assume-unchanged "$symlink"; 
    done; 
    }; __git_rm_symlinks'

git config --global alias.checkout-symlinks '!__git_checkout_symlinks(){
    POS=$'\''/'\''; DOS=$'\''\\\\'\''; 
    for symlink in `git ls-files -s | grep -E "^120000" | cut -f2`; 
    do 
        git update-index --no-assume-unchanged "$symlink"; 
        if [ -d "$symlink" ]; then 
            dossymlink=${symlink//$POS/$DOS}; 
            cmd //C rmdir //S //Q "$dossymlink"; 
        fi; 
        git  checkout -- "$symlink"; 
        echo "Restored git symlink $symlink <<===>> `cat $symlink`"; 
    done; 
    }; __git_checkout_symlinks'

git rm-symlinks
```

I have also tried the commands in the SO answer to [Git symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754068/129486), which produces the same results.

**Output:**

The output I get after running the above commands is a little odd, so I'm not sure if the script is successful.

```
User@Computer /cygdrive/c/.../Local/devstack/edx-platform/edx-platform $./symlinks-fix.sh
**Git checkout output**
...
Checking out files: 100% (6983/6983), done.
HEAD is now at 222bdd9 Merge pull request #10411 from edx/mobile/course-blocks-api

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\...\Local\devstack\edx-platform\edx-platform>
```

Why does it go into the Windows-style command prompt at the end?  This is where I'm unsure if the git commands are working.

**In Vagrant:**

After running `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh`, I get the following errors when running `paver devstack lms` (similar output for `paver devstack studio`):

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo su edxapp
edxapp@precise64:~/edx-platform$ paver devstack lms
...
pip install -q --disable-pip-version-check --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/github.txt
  Could not find a tag or branch '96e1922348bfe6d99201b9512a9ed946c87b7e0b', assuming commit.
  .... 20 similar ....
  Could not find a tag or branch 'e7a6c95c300e95c51e42bfd1eba70489c05a6527', assuming commit.

pip install -q --disable-pip-version-check --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/local.txt
pip install -q --disable-pip-version-check --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/base.txt
  Requested meliae==0.4.0 (from -r requirements/edx/base.txt (line 47)), but installing version 0.4.0.final.0
pip install -q --disable-pip-version-check --exists-action w -r requirements/edx/post.txt
python manage.py cms --settings=devstack reindex_course --setup
2015-11-06 01:37:40,353 WARNING 4797 [xblock.plugin] plugin.py:147 - Unable to load XBlock 'html'
    Traceback...
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/js/common_static/js/vendor/draggabilly.pkgd.js'
2015-11-06 01:37:40,660 WARNING 4797 [xblock.plugin] plugin.py:147 - Unable to load XBlock 'course_info'
    Traceback...
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/js/common_static/js/vendor/draggabilly.pkgd.js'
    Traceback...
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/js/common_static/js/vendor/draggabilly.pkgd.js'
    Traceback ...
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/js/common_static/js/vendor/draggabilly.pkgd.js'
    Traceback ...
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/js/common_static/js/vendor/draggabilly.pkgd.js'

Build failed running pavelib.servers.devstack: Subprocess return code: 1
```

From what I understand, this is a problem with symlinks (See [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/edx-code/vcQiMkWZtb0/sXdPxCxgm7UJ) post on Google groups).

Am I running the above symlinks script properly?  How can I check if the symlinks have been dealt with successfully?

**Other attempts:**

Following the suggestions in the google group (link above), I have also made the following adjustments:

- setting the VAGRANT_USE_VBOXFS = true
- using the Vagrantfile provided [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/edx/configuration/master/vagrant/release/devstack/Vagrantfile)
- setting the environment variable OPENEDX_RELEASE="named-release/cypress"
- installing libxmlsec1 from Vagrant instance.

After multiple `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant provision`'s, I still have the same `IOError: [Error 20] Not a directory` problem.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Versions:

- Windows version: 8
- Vagrant version: 1.7.4
- VirtualBox version: 5.0.8
- openEdx release: named-release/cypress

Comment: Are you trying to create/use symlinks in Windows, or are you trying to create/use symlinks in VirtualBox (assuming a linux VM)?

Comment: @Jonathan I'm trying to use symlinks in files that are stored on my Windows machine and shared via VirtualBox to a linux VM... At least I think that's how vagrant works.

Comment: There is a bug in the first script where `hash=$(echo "$1" | git hash-object -w --stdin); ` should be `hash=$(echo -n "$1" | git hash-object -w --stdin); ` (note the additional "-n")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by your cydrive path is wrong.

Try to change in `c:\cygwin\etc\fstab`

`none /cydrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0`

to

`none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0`

refs: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive

**UPDATE:**

From CMD Type 'bash' and then copy/paste the contents of the script

If you get the same result try:

Open .gitconfig (with Notepad++ or similar) and add this section if it is not yet existing

```
[alias]
add-symlink = "!__git_add_symlink(){\n    dst=$(echo \"$2\")/../$(echo \"$1\"); \n    if [ -e \"$dst\" ]; then \n        hash=$(echo -n \"$1\" | git hash-object -w --stdin); \n        git update-index --add --cacheinfo 120000 \"$hash\" \"$2\"; \n        git checkout -- \"$2\"; \n    else \n        echo \"ERROR: Target $dst does not exist!\"; \n        echo \"       Not creating invalid symlink.\"; \n    fi; \n    }; __git_add_symlink \"$1\" \"$2\""
rm-symlink = "!__git_rm_symlink(){\n    git checkout -- \"$1\"; link=$(echo \"$1\"); \n    POS=$'/'; DOS=$'\\\\\\\\'; \n    doslink=${link//$POS/$DOS}; \n    dest=$(dirname \"$link\")/$(cat \"$link\"); \n    dosdest=${dest//$POS/$DOS}; \n    if [ -f \"$dest\" ]; then \n        rm -f \"$link\"; \n        cmd //C mklink //H \"$doslink\" \"$dosdest\"; \n    elif [ -d \"$dest\" ]; then \n        rm -f \"$link\"; \n        cmd //C mklink //J \"$doslink\" \"$dosdest\"; \n    else \n        echo \"ERROR: Something went wrong when processing $1 . . .\"; \n        echo \"       $dest may not actually exist as a valid target.\"; \n    fi; \n    }; __git_rm_symlink \"$1\""
rm-symlinks = "!__git_rm_symlinks(){\n    for symlink in `git ls-files -s | grep -E \"^120000\" | cut -f2`; \n    do \n        git rm-symlink \"$symlink\"; \n        git update-index --assume-unchanged \"$symlink\"; \n    done; \n    }; __git_rm_symlinks"
checkout-symlinks = "!__git_checkout_symlinks(){\n    POS=$'/'; DOS=$'\\\\\\\\'; \n    for symlink in `git ls-files -s | grep -E \"^120000\" | cut -f2`; \n    do \n        git update-index --no-assume-unchanged \"$symlink\"; \n        if [ -d \"$symlink\" ]; then \n            dossymlink=${symlink//$POS/$DOS}; \n            cmd //C rmdir //S //Q \"$dossymlink\"; \n        fi; \n        git  checkout -- \"$symlink\"; \n        echo \"Restored git symlink $symlink <<===>> `cat $symlink`\"; \n    done; \n    }; __git_checkout_symlinks"
```

This will create some git commands for symlinks

*Note: File uses Unix line endings, don't edit with windows Notepad!*

Then execute the commands

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
git rm-symlinks
```

I tested it in my env and it works

Comment: I get the same error after I edit that file.  It also still goes to windows-style command after running the script.  I am using cygwin in administrator mode, and `mount` shows the following (after editing fstab): `C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
`

Comment: this "option" in fstab is for auto mounted drives It allows you to have `/cygdrive/c/windows` when you change it it will become /c/windows
Seems you need to add all manually mounted paths in fstab as it is described in cygwin manual

Comment: I edited the answer to add some other stuff. I think your `.sh` lineendings might be off. They should be UNIX style.

Comment: The .sh line endings are UNIX style, but I think you're right about my cygdrive having some issues, because even after I edited the .gitconfig and ran the commands, it still didn't work.  However!  I opened up the git bash terminal, tried the commands again, and it worked! Thanks!