# Using the same code in multiple directories of a Git repository

Tags: git, github, symlink, git-submodules

I have a Git repository. In this repository is a directory called `core_code`, which contains common code used in several pieces of software (like a common library). There are also directories called `program_alpha` and `program_beta`, which contain two different pieces of software but are related. Both `program_alpha` and `program_beta` rely on `core_code` to function, and when the software is run, the `core_code` needs to be in the program directory. So when I'm running the software, both `program_alpha` and `program_beta` need to have copies of `core_code` within them (for reasons specific to the application, the `core_code` must be in the program root and cannot be referenced from somewhere else).

So, I'm looking for a way to have `core_code` available in all `program_*` directories, but without duplicating it. Initially I wanted to do something like have a symlink in each `program_*` directory that points to the `core_code` directory, but I'm using the code cross-platform and Git does not hand Windows symlinks well at all. I also must keep all this code in the same repository, so I can't have a separate repo for `core_code` and then use submodules in the `program_*` directories.

Any suggestions for the best way to do this? It would be so simple if symlinks worked better in Git.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `post-checkout` hook on Windows machines. Try [this](https://github.com/elliottcarlson/git-symlink-checkout-hook/blob/master/post_checkout) implementation on github. You can find more discussion on this method in another question: [Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5917249/6238076)

If your repo is meaned to be shared among a large group of users, it is better to copy the `core_code` with `Makefile` or `configure` script. Don't rely on git-symlink or hook.