# How to use symlinks created by Windows git with Cygwin

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, cygwin, symlink

I am using Jenkins on a Windows machine to build a Cygwin program. Recently that started to fail.

I turned out that was because Windows' `git` seems to represent symbolic links in the repo as plain text files.

There are two possible approaches to solve this:

1. Use Cygwin's `git` to do the checkout.
2. Convert the links (a.k.a. plain text files) to Cygwin links

The first turned out to be not as simple as I wished, pointing to Cygwin's `git.exe` was not enough as we need the `cygwin1.dll` in the path. This and some other issues made me abandon this apporach. I'm interested in suggestions on how to do that, in essence turning a Windows Jenkins into a Cygwin Jenkins.

However, turning Windows `git` "links" into Cygwin links seemed feasable. What would be a simple way to do that and could be run as an initial step in the Jenkins build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple bash script to find all the "links", easy since they are marked with flags 120000 according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5930443/204658). Then it was a simple matter to just pick up the target filename (the content of the text file) and then replace the file with a symbolic link.

Since it is a bash script it can easily be used from Cygwin and MSys.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38140374/204658
#
# Script to convert symbolic links created by a windows git
# clone/checkout to cygwin links. When a typical Windows git checks
# out a symbolic link from the repo it (MsysGit, at least) tend to
# produce text files with flag 120000 and the link target file name as
# the content.  Strategy would simply be to find all those and replace
# by cygwin links.
#
# This will work if you are not planning on commiting anything, e.g.
# in a Jenkins, or other CI, build environment

for f in `git ls-files -s | awk '$1 == "120000" {print $4}'`
do
    # echo $f is a symlink pointing to $dir/$target
    dir=$(dirname "${f}")
    pushd "$dir" 2>&1 > /dev/null
    file=$(basename "$f")
    target=`cat "$file"`
    rm "$file"
    ln -s "$target" "$file"
    popd 2>&1 > /dev/null
done
```

Comment: You might want to make your awk use `^120000` or `$1 == "120000"` as the test, so that it will not fire on files whose hash happens to contain `120000` or whose name contains `120000`.  (You may also run into issues with file names that contain whitespace, but this is a bit harder to work around with simple scripting.)

Comment: Thanks, @torek, updated script with `$1 = "120000"` and more quotes to alleviate space problems.

Comment: Alas, the `$4` in awk will have already mangled a whitespace-containing name.  (This is why `git ls-files` has `-z`, but to use that option you have to get pretty crazy with special Bash tricks, or write the whole thing in Python instead, or some such...  Without `-z` Git encodes whitespace, perhaps using `read` in Bash will just work?)

Comment: Yes, didn't consider that... What about `git ls-files -s | awk '$1="120000"{print $0}' | cut -d\  -f4-`?

Comment: I'd have to experiment: without `-z`, `git ls-files -s` does do some encoding, so maybe `$4` itself is fine and we just need to let bash `read` handle escapes.  (What if a file name contains a literal backslash? Just need a torture-test Git repo... :-) )