# How to dereference symbolic links in git repository when downloading?

Tags: git, symlink

Since I'm working on Windows, once download repository, all symbolic links in repo turn into unavailable files.

I want to get hard-copied files instead of symbolic links which are not recognizable on Windows. It doesn't matter to preserve history.

When a git repository contains lots of symbolic links, how can I get properly dereferenced files when downloading them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Symlinks in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Windows 10, you can enable developer mode to support symbolic links from Linux, BSD, and other flavors of Unix: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

Is this adequate to solve your issue?  If not, your best option is to write a script to locate all the links, and assuming they point to files in the repo (not Linux specific files like `/usr/bin/cd`) replace them locally with the actual files.  Note, you'll not what to check these in.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Git handles symlinks by itself.
With an option -c core.symlinks=true, Windows Git can create windows symbolic links.

Here's more detail: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/Symbolic-Links