# CGREEN compilation error: ‘assertion_tests’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing

When I try to compile cgreen unit testing framework in cygwin64 I get this error:

```
[ 34%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/cgreen_cpp_tests.dir/assertion_tests.cpp.o
/home/Administrator/cgreen/tests/assertion_tests.cpp:1:1: error: ‘assertion_tests’ does not name a type 
assertion_tests.c 
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/cgreen_cpp_tests.dir/build.make:63: tests/CMakeFiles/cgreen_cpp_tests.dir/assertion_tests.cpp.o] Error 1 
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1615: tests/CMakeFiles/cgreen_cpp_tests.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
```

I have searched on google with no result.

I am using cygwin64 with cmake 3.6.2 and gcc 7.3.0

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `assertion_tests.cpp` file is a symlink, see [github cgreen repo](https://github.com/cgreen-devs/cgreen/blob/master/tests/assertion_tests.cpp). Sadly, on windows symlink is converted into textfile with the path to the file it should link to. You need to convert the file into actual link, as well all the others links in the [cgreen repo](https://github.com/cgreen-devs/cgreen/tree/master/tests), and there are some. Some help on how to do it may be better found on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows).

Comment: yes, that was the problem. After converting those files into real links it compiled ok. I was wondering why cpp files had c file names inside.. good to know. Thanks!