# Git windows clone symlink

Tags: git

I have a git repo that is used to build a custom live-boot image (debian-live based). I modify the repo on my Windows machine, but pull it to a Linux build server to actually build the image. Some of the files are symlinks, pointing to other locations on the build server (well, actually in chroot during build - these are files provided with debian-live). So, I don't need these files to be symlinks in Windows, I just need them to have the "120000" file type in git. I cloned the repo to start work on a similar live-boot image, but the symlink file types weren't preserved. They have the same hash and contents, just a different git type. How do I change them??

Comment: If you are using Windows 10 I would recommend to install and use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) for cloning the git repo.

Comment: At what point did you determine that they have a "different git type"?  ie, what command did you run that you noticed this?  Are they different in the index?  Or only in the working tree?

Comment: The second answer here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symlinks-in-windows

Comment: Just to clarify - I have this setup working, my problem is cloning it. @EdwardThomson If I run "git ls-tree HEAD" in the folder containing the relevant files, the original repo shows "120000 blob <hash> <file>. My new, cloned repo shows "100644 blob <same hash> <same file>".

Comment: Could you paste the actual commands beginning with the clone and ending with the ls-tree HEAD?  This is unexpected and I fear that something is very wrong - those modes are part of the tree and thus part of the commit (and thus make up the commit ID).  So it would be either ls-tree misreporting a tree or something else odd going on...

Comment: I used the TortoiseGit GUI to create the repo. Now I think of it, I think I created the new repo after just copying + pasting the contents of the original one into a new folder. This would explain the discrepancy, but is there a way to recreate those symlinks?