# Can I share a subdirectory with other subdirectories in the same git repo?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-subtree

Let's say my repo structure is currently something like:

```
ROOT
--LanguageA
----Project A-LangA
----Project B-LangA
----Project C-LangA
--Language B
----Project A-LangB
------SharedFile-1
------SharedFile-2
------SharedFile-3
----Project B-LangB
------SharedFile-1
------SharedFile-2
------SharedFile-3
----Project C-LangB
------SharedFile-1
------SharedFile-2
------SharedFile-3
```

Currently, if I need to update `SharedFile-1`, I need to do so within each `Project` directory. Is it possible to use `git submodule` or `git subtree` to create something like:

```
ROOT
--LanguageA
----Project A-LangA
----Project B-LangA
----Project C-LangA
--Language B
----Project A-LangB
------SharedFile-1 (auto-updating clone)
------SharedFile-2 (auto-updating clone)
------SharedFile-3 (auto-updating clone)
----Project B-LangB
------SharedFile-1 (auto-updating clone)
------SharedFile-2 (auto-updating clone)
------SharedFile-3 (auto-updating clone)
----Project C-LangB
------SharedFile-1 (auto-updating clone)
------SharedFile-2 (auto-updating clone)
------SharedFile-3 (auto-updating clone)
----Language B Shared Files
------SharedFile-1
------SharedFile-2
------SharedFile-3
```

...such that I only have to make edits to `ROOT/Language B/Language B Shared Files/*` and the changes auto-update in each `ROOT/Language B/Project *` dir when a user clones the whole repo?

I know I can break it out into a separate repo. But is it possible to have the above structure? I also know I can create an automation script that does this, but I'm trying to use the above structure, to the extent possible.

Comment: Are any of your contributors on Windows? Git supports symlinks, but [I don't think that plays nicely with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5917249/354577).

Comment: Most are, but not all. Needs to be cross-platform. I'm considering using pre-commit hooks to copy the files over and commit them