# Git status does not recognize directory junctions

Tags: git

I use `Git v2.26.2` on Windows 10 and `git status` to check my directory status. During the compilation of my application, a tool created a junction in my directory which is fine. But `git status` returns no changes to the directory.

How can I make `git status` or `git clean` aware of the existence of any link or junction that doesn't belong to the repo?

P.S. `git clean -xdf` doesn't remove the junction either

Comment: I suppose you meant 2.26.2, not 2.6.2 as a Git version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A junction would be seen as an empty repository which would not register with Git.

a true directory symlink, with a [Git for Windows enabling symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42137273/6309), would record a file with the destination path in it.
(`git config core.symlinks true`)

Comment: But shouldn't git see/treat the junction like as a mounting point on Linux and treat it as it would be a real directory?

Comment: @DanielStephens On Linux, maybe, but this is Windows here, and junctions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions) is a link between folders: Git does not register folders alone.