# Add a file to an Android Studio project as a reference instead of a copy

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a file (json) outside of my Android Studio project root folder which is used by another projects. I want to keep the file outside of the project root and have it as part of my Android Studio project so I can read it in runtime as an asset. I need behavior similar to what Xcode does when you copy file as reference.

Is it possible to add the file to the Android Studio project as a reference without copying it?

Comment: Have you tried using a hardlink or symlink? (assuming Linux or macOS as your developer platform -- I think Windows has equivalents but possibly under different names)

Comment: The environment is both, Windows and Mac so having only simlinks won't help unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW my rant: This is an insane restriction. I have just started writing a fairly complex set of native libraries targeting droid and iOS. So I have a lot of files which are shared and I keep in a common repo. Furthermore, I want to build on Windows in addition to Mac/linux. Symlinks are still a PITA on Windows (despite SO answer [Git symbolic links in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symbolic-links-in-windows)) and problematic to integrate with Cygwin (so I can share shell scripts between all platforms). It is possible to avoid symlinks by keeping CMakeLists.txt up-to-date and referencing the original source files - but Android Studio complains about "non-project files" when I open one of the .cpp files (for example to fix a compile error). And in general it is a major irritation.

Why on earth Google would decide that baking file refs into Android Studio is a bad idea after all these years is beyond me. File refs work fine in Xcode and VS. (I cannot believe I just said something positive about Xcode - but that's a different rant for a different day.) But I'm an oddball - I don't care for CMake and I certainly despise gradle (which likes to break existing projects on a minor gradle upgrade because...why not).

So my CMakeLists.txt looks like the following. I haven't yet written my script to generate my files lists automatically and integrate them using CMake 'include' - because I do have some actual programming to do as well :)

```
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}-static STATIC
    # List C/C++ source files with relative paths to this CMakeLists.txt.
    tc3framework.cpp

    # tc3_core
    "${tc3_core_src}/tc3-core.cpp"
    "${tc3_core_src}/tc3-exception-support.cpp"
    "${tc3_core_src}/tc3-exceptions.cpp"
    "${tc3_core_src}/tc3-invoker.cpp"
    "${tc3_core_src}/tc3-json.cpp"
    [...]
)
```

Hope this helps and I hope AS dev team decides that a file reference inside a project is something which real human beings would appreciate having.