# Can't able to setup project locally with yarn

Tags: typescript, yarn-v2

I am trying to setup project called https://github.com/calcom/cal.com  but it give me following error when I run `yarn dx`

```
@calcom/prisma:db-up: failed to read C:\Learning\Open-Source\cal.com\packages\prisma\.env: line 1: unexpected character "/" in variable name
@calcom/prisma:db-up: failed to read C:\Learning\Open-Source\cal.com\packages\prisma\.env: line 1: unexpected character "/" in variable name
@calcom/prisma:db-up: ERROR: command finished with error: command (C:\Learning\Open-Source\cal.com\packages\prisma) yarn run db-up exited (1)
command (C:\Learning\Open-Source\cal.com\packages\prisma) yarn run db-up exited (1)

 Tasks:    1 successful, 2 total
Cached:    0 cached, 2 total
  Time:    7.73s
Failed:    @calcom/prisma#db-up

 ERROR  run failed: command  exited (1)
```

So can anyone help me solve above issue note that I followed all setups which is available in `readme.md`

So can anyone help me solve above issue note that I followed all setups which is available in `readme.md`

Comment: `"unexpected character "/" in variable name in file .env"` you may guess what that mean and post the info required to answer

Comment: @Dimava my .env file `(\cal.com\packages\prisma\)` content is `../../.env` means it refer to global file which is present in root folder

Comment: I guess it was a symlink and it got cloned incorrectly

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917249/git-symbolic-links-in-windows

Comment: issue has been resolved [ISSUE #10030](https://github.com/calcom/cal.com/issues/10030)

Answer (score 0):

I also get this error when I start exploring cal.com project,It says like there is problem in cal.com\packages\prisma.env as far as I know. You can do one thing just copy **cal.com.env** to the **cal.com\packages\prisma.env** and then run yarn dx. It will start working .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).