# Creating a Unity package's folder "Samples~" hides it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/cus-samples.html), one has to create a `Samples~` folder, **with a tilde at the end**:

> To add samples to your package:
>
> Put the asset files or example C# code files under the Samples~ folder. You can have more than one sample in a package: each subfolder of the Samples~ folder contains one sample.
>
> Note: The tilde character (~) tells Unity to ignore the contents the Samples~ folder. Such folders aren’t tracked with .meta files.

When you do that, the folder actually disappears in Unity!

Which means that you can no longer open the sample scene, edit it, etc, it's gone...

Obviously, that makes no sense at all because the sample is part of the package.

Digging into the Package Manager one can see an *Import* button:

[image]

Clicking it will deploy the samples in `Assets/Samples/...`, that's great news but that doesn't really answer the question on how to keep authoring that package's samples.

Still in the documentation, one has to fill *package.json* about samples contained in the package, did that but nothing appears.

Tried restarting Unity but that didn't change anything.

**Question:**

How can one author a package's sample if one cannot access it from within Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

In the `package.json` manifest in order to make it importable you additionally add a `samples` section like e.g.

```
samples : [
    {
       "displayName": "<name-to-appear-in-the-UI>",
       "description": "<brief-description>",
       "path": "Samples~/<sample-subfolder>"
    }
]
```

---

Now to the how to deal with this as the package developer:

There are different ways, but for me the best approach seems to use [*Symbolic Links*](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-links).

Anyway in order to edit your package properly you need to embed it into a Unity project e.g. into

```
Packages/YourPackage
```

Again there are different ways for this

- Some do this on he repository basis and commit the entire Unity project including the package.
- Others use `git submodules`.
- And yet others (like me) even do this as well via *Symbolic Links*.

Then in addition I keep the `Samples~` folder so it is correctly committed into the repository.

And then in that development project I create a symbolic link as

```
Assets/Samples
```

which points to

```
../Packages/YourPackage/Samples~
```

I can recommend [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html). With this installed you can simply drag and drop your `Samples~` folder while holding **right mouse button** and then from the context menu select `Drop as` -> `Symbolic Link`. Then you can simply rename the symbolic link to `Samples` which will not affect the targeted `Samples~`

You will get a warning though

> Disabling directory monitoring for current editor session. Found symlinks in project which cannot be used with directory monitoring. Directory monitoring settings can be changed in preferences

tbh I never had any issues so far with that approach and just ignored the warning. It anyway only happens in your local dev project. In [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-symbolic-links-with-directory-monitoring.1293993/) they suggested to rather go for hard links. I never tried this - might be worth a shot but I don't know how hardlinks work in `git`, as long as it is a relative path symbolic links can simply be commited into the repository (basically just a file with a path)

Comment: Symbolic links for Unity, that's a great hack! Just one thing, one probably wants something else than `Assets/Samples` because doing so, other packages would deploy their sample into your package samples (in the case you want to try samples from another packages while crafting your own package), you'd then end up with unrelated samples in your own package sample folder.

Comment: @aybe True you can of course do it just the way the package is going to be imported and do e.g. `Assets/Samples/YourPackage/YourSample` .. for import via PackagaManager they even include the package version in the path

Comment: Tried symlinks, that immediately worked but you get *Disabling directory monitoring for current editor session. Found symlinks in project which cannot be used with directory monitoring. Directory monitoring settings can be changed in preferences.*, let's see if that can remedied somehow using another approach...

Comment: Anyway that's not much of a big deal, I'll just keep on crafting the package and figure that one out later, thanks! 

Comment: @aybe yeah that's one I usually just ignore - you know what you are doing and it's only going to appear in your dev project - didn't have issues so far with that tbh. Here is a thread https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-symbolic-links-with-directory-monitoring.1293993/ they suggest using hard links instead .. never did that either so might be worth a shot

Comment: Actually, you are right, my bad... it can be `Assets/Samples/xyz`... they add them into subfolders. Yep, hard-link did it but the other way around, creating a hard-link from `Assets/Samples/xyz` to `Assets/xyz/Samples~`. 

Comment: @aybe be aware that those will only work local - git afaik doesn't support hard links. sym links you can commit as file into the repository without any issue as long as they use a relative path within the repo

Comment: It seems that it isn't as straightforward to make a package, the symlink when committed, isn't restored when pulled, the hard links as you mentioned ended up being worse. I'm probably going to ask another question in a few hours! :)

Comment: @aybe double check that the symlink is using a relative path and not an absolute one, should be working with git as it is basically just a file with the path pointer

Comment: It turns out that symbolic links are troublesome, while they fix the actual problem, they introduce another one. It took me a while to clone the project to assess whether they work properly, the answer on how to get them working in Windows being here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761201/361899 I might just look at another alternative you suggested since that doesn't work out of the box and that's pretty annoying.

Comment: Evaluated the different alternatives, symlink are the least intrusive minus the annoyance. There's a guy who seemingly put something to get it right (https://medium.com/openupm/how-to-maintain-upm-package-part-1-7b4daf88d4c4) but well... using subtrees, rewriting history, deleting branches, force push... hell no, it's becoming ridiculously complex; the simpler the better.